# data from post api is not sent when hosted on cpanel

Tags: api, codeigniter, curl, cpanel

i have a form data that i send with api post using curl, on cpanel curl is installed, but when running post api function, data doesn't go to database

is there a wrong configuration?
here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => '',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

when it is run on localhost there is no problem, but when it is hosted on cpanel it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CURL function is not enabled on your cPanel PHP Settings?

Comment: cURL is installed on server